# Printing last column in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

My h.csv file contains 7 columns of float data type and the delimiter is a white space

my program in python is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np 

h = np.array(pd.read_csv("h.csv", delim_whitespace=True))
print(h)
print("\n")
X = h[:,0:6]
print(X)
print("\n")
y = h[:,6]
print(y)
print("\n")
```

I am encountering the problem with the print statement that prints y;

Actually it has to print the last column of my file, but it is not doing so.

The arrays 'h' and 'X' are printing well. The print 'y' statement is not printing the last column of the matrix, but printing some random numbers.

Comment: check the source file, it seems they may have space and the end. if you have less column, then following error will be shown `IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6`

Comment: @Shijo It is not showing any wrror, but printing random numbers...

Comment: please share the sample data

Comment: @Shijo http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00243/yacht_hydrodynamics.data

Comment: I dont see any issues with the code and the numbers are looking correct.But noticed that you dont have a header, so add parameter header=None to  ' h = np.array(pd.read_csv("h.csv", delim_whitespace=True,header=None)) '

Comment: @Shijo I tried it too, but not getting last column......

Comment: paste your sample input data , expected output and current output here, not in any other site, we will try to help you

Answer (score 0):

just add names to the columns and print by them, for example:

```
h = pd.read_csv("h.csv", delim_whitespace=True, names = ["A", "B", "C", "X","Y","Z","P"])

print (h.A)
print (h.B)
print (h.Y)
print (h.P)
```

Comment: first of all, you are getting the Scientific Notation of the numbers second of all you don't need numpy to add the csv to the array. pandas will do. you are not getting the first row when you are importing it like that.

Comment: How to suppress scientific notation?

Comment: my edited answer should help you better now.